# windows phone 8.0 MediaElement plays sound without any call

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

When i click button no 1 , MediaElement will play the pronunciation of that sentence . then if i click button no 2 i will navigate to SoundRecord page . then if i click the back button to previous page (as you see in the picture ) again , MediaElement play the previous pronunciation that you have chosen without call any function ...
what is the reason and how can i fix this problem ?

[image]

also this is the code for play the sound files :

```
public void PlayPronunciation(string fileName, MediaElement soundPlayer)
    {
        var path = string.Format("Assets/Audio/{0}.mp3", fileName);
        soundPlayer.Source = new Uri(path, UriKind.Relative);
        soundPlayer.AutoPlay = true;

        if (soundPlayer.CurrentState == MediaElementState.Stopped)
            soundPlayer.Play();
    }
```

For temporary solution in page unload event i did something like this but i think this not a nice way to fix my problem :

```
private void PhoneApplicationPage_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
SoundPlayer.AutoPlay = false;
}
```

Comment: just remove the `soundPlayer.AutoPlay = true;` if you use `if (soundPlayer.CurrentState == MediaElementState.Stopped)
            soundPlayer.Play();`

Comment: Thanks for replying , i did but unfortunately it does not work :(

Comment: set  `AutoPlay="False"` in the xaml and delete every AutoPlay= true from your code

Comment: i did what you said , but MediaElement does not play audio file any more ...

Comment: Change this: `if (soundPlayer.CurrentState == MediaElementState.Stopped)`
to this:  `if (soundPlayer.CurrentState != MediaElementState.Playing)`

Comment: @csharpwinphonexaml Thank you for help i solved my problem with your help, the only thing i forgot was adding mediaelemet to LayoutRoot as a child element .

Answer (score 1):

- Remove this line: `soundPlayer.AutoPlay = true;` if you use

  ```
  if (soundPlayer.CurrentState == MediaElementState.Stopped)
     soundPlayer.Play();`
  ```
- Set `AutoPlay="False"` in the xaml and delete any `soundPlayer.AutoPlay=true;` from your code
- Change this:

  ```
  if (soundPlayer.CurrentState == MediaElementState.Stopped)
  ```

  to this:

  ```
  if (soundPlayer.CurrentState != MediaElementState.Playing)
  ```